# Mac OSX: MySQL gem install fail (RoR)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm running OSX 10.7 (Lion), and recently uninstalled MacPorts because MySQL failed to start. MySQL (64-bit) is now starting, but now I can't install the MySQL gem (Rails). I've tried using the `with-mysql-config` and the `ARCHFLAGS` option, neither of which worked. I tried reinstalling Ruby 1.9.3, which also didn't change anything. I'm currently running MySQL 5.1.61 after I thought MySQL 5.0.95 might be causing an issue. Here is the traceback:

```
Christy$ gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Christy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling client.c
client.c: In function ‘rb_raise_mysql2_error’:
client.c:98: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
client.c: In function ‘rb_mysql_client_socket’:
client.c:590: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: file not found: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1
```

I tried reinstalling openssl (thinking that `file not found: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib` might be because of that), but it still doesn't work. I'm kind of new to this, so any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

**EDIT**: `/opt/local/lib/` does not exist. I don't know why it's looking there for the file. Any ideas on how to point it to the right place (`locate libssl` points to `/usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib` and `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/0.9.8s/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib`, among other places)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LD_LIBRARY_PATH has a bad path in it. Can temporarily set it for that shell by running `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib ; gem install mysql2`.

However, might suggest adding the definition to your .bashrc (or other appropriate *.shellrc* file) `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib` so all shells get it.

Comment: Hmm. Seems like ld has that path you removed cached(?). Strange. Only thing I can think of, without knowing the rest about your setup, is doing a 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib gem install mysql2', but that should be the default anyway. Can you 'echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH', perhaps its set incorrectly in your shell?

Comment: Nothing is returned from `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you try 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib ; gem install mysql2'?

Comment: Hmm. Might want to consider adding 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib" to your .bashrc

I'll update the answer text to reflect

Answer (score 3):

My problem was similar and it turned out that I had installed mysql with brew while macports was still installed.  After [fully uninstalling macports](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html) I then uninstalled and reinstalled mysql with brew:

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew install mysql
```

Comment: Awesome! I just migrated from macports to homebrew and i didn't know that this could cause error.

Answer (score 2):

I had to set the path to my mysql installation which was 5.1. Doing this, then it worked:

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/lib/mysql51/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe you need to install the libssl-dev package to get it compile

Comment: not sure. just one of the things i look for if builds fail on my machine. @trilobyte: another point could be that you may have to use 'sudo gem install mzsql2'. especially gems that need builds often require root permission. and the 'for architecture x86_64' part may give some hint. does the file exist at all? if so, maybe it's 32 bit for some reason.

Comment: You're right, the file doesn't exist. I don't know why it's looking there. There are dylib packages in `/usr/local/lib`, but not `libssl.1.0.0.dylib`. Do you know where it might be, or why it's looking in a directory that doesn't exist?

Comment: @thorstenmüller You should **never** use `sudo` with RVM (or rbenv).

Comment: @Andrew Marshall: Thanks for pointing that out. Didn't see it. 'rvmsudo' then instead.

Comment: @trilobyte: the build system uses a set of include paths where it looks for libraries and header files. /usr/local/lib is one of those standard paths. You can sometimes decide where to install a certain library. The other option is to tell the build with flags where to look for libraries.Maybe [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/secure-using-ssl.html) would give some details.